# Node.js: How to solve Asynchronous Log Overlaps in a Terminal UI?

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, asynchronous, terminal

### What I'm trying to do

I'm building a node.js logging tool [logminer](https://github.com/adamhalasz/logminer) to learn and expirement about logging/monitoring services. I found an interesting problem that I couldn't solve yet:

### The problem

Let's say we want to log the URL and the IP and Location of the Client when an HTTP Request is emitted to see what users are entering into the omnibar (or for whatever reason).

Let's say the URL is logged right away, but for the IP we do an Async Request (maybe we want to get the location based on the IP)

```
// hypothetical http request handler
function httpRequestHandler(req, res){
    // first log (after 0 seconds)
    var log = new Log('Request')

    if(req.url = 'home'){
        // second log (after 0.1 seconds)
        log.message('welcome home')
        // ... do something
    } else {
        // second log (after 0.1 seconds);
        log.message('the url is', req.url)

        asyncFunction(req, function(value){
             // third log (after 5 seconds)
             log.message('the ip is ', value.ip)
             log.message('the location is ', value.location)
             // ... do something
        })
    }
}
```

**The output can very quickly become from this:**

(at +0 seconds) User Requests: http://example.com/other

```
Request
 in Request: welcome home
```

(at +5 seconds) User Requests: http://example.com/

```
Request
 in Request: the url is http://example.com/other
 in Request: the ip is 127.0.0.1
 in Request: the location is 'San Francisco'
```

---

**Into this:**

- 4 requests after another with 1 second between page request
- (+0 second) User Requests: http://example.com/
- (+1 second) User Requests: http://example.com/other <-- this needs 5 -seconds to finish
- (+2 second) User Requests: http://example.com/
- (+3 second) User Requests: http://example.com/

.

```
// at +0 second
Request
 in Request: welcome home

// at +1 second
Request
 in Request: the url is http://example.com/other

// at +2 second
Request
 in Request: welcome home

// at +3 second
Request
 in Request: welcome home


// at +5 second
 in Request: the ip is 127.0.0.1
 in Request: the location is 'San Francisco'
```

As you can see the one with +5 seconds creates confusion especially because it actually looks like this:

```
Request
 in Request: welcome home
 in Request: the ip is 127.0.0.1
 in Request: the location is 'San Francisco'
```

And this doesn't make any sense! The 2nd and the 3rd rows are within a different Scope from the 1st one and this makes it seem like they are the same. With many concurent users this is completely unreadable. That's why I think there has to be a way to identify to the origins's of each line, that's why I have an ID in logminer. Including a Scope ID in every row works but it's still very hard to connect the dots and it takes a lots of screen-space as well.

[image: logminer scope id]

### The Question

Now my question is it possible to group things in an asynchronous environment based on their Scope without an ID or using Paging/Filters without a GUI?

Is this a design problem that cannot be solved because of the linear nature of terminals so a GUI is required at this point or am I missing something?

What are the best ways to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual solution to this is to not output your message in pieces that are separated in time because of async results.

Instead, accumulate all the data for your entire message into a string or various variables and then output the whole message at once.  This will avoid some part of the message being output and then sometime later (after an async operation) so other part of the message being output.

If you want to make sure you know "when" the event occurred, then record a timestamp from the beginning of the event and include that in the message too.

For example:

```
// hypothetical http request handler
function httpRequestHandler(req, res){
    // first log (after 0 seconds)
    var log = new Log('Request');

    if(req.url = 'home'){
        // second log (after 0.1 seconds)
        log.message('welcome home');
        // ... do something
    } else {
        asyncFunction(req, function(value){
            log.message('the url is', req.url);
            log.message('the ip is ', value.ip);
            log.message('the location is ', value.location);
            // ... do something
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The usual way is to gather all the information and print in stages. The problem becomes when you're impatiently waiting for things to finish and your async program has lots to do and you want some status update.

In that case you can use you can use the nodejs builtin readline to hack the terminal lines and overwrite the old information effectively dividing it into sections. However there is a few libraries out there that already do that, take [logger master](https://www.npmjs.com/package/logger_master) that does exactly that (find code @ [github](https://github.com/ROUJE/logger-master)). Depends on how slow your program is.